# Why is Swift function definition syntax redundant?

Tags: objective-c, swift, go

In C/C++/Java/Go, we use , to separate parameters:

```
(a int, b int)
```

In Objective C, we use : to indicate parameters:

```
:(int)a :(int)b
```

In Swift, we have to use both : and , :

```
(a:int, b:int)
```

Is the redundancy necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift might have external and internal parameter names:

```
(external internal:Int)
```

It would create a lot of ambiguity if there wasn't distinctive separators.

Comment: I see. Thanks.

External/internal parameters make Swift code looks so similar to Objective C code, that I am not sure if it worths a new language...

Comment: They are optional. You can do `(_ internal:Int)` to no use them.

Comment: @cxwangyi it is not, but for other reasons.

Comment: @Kirsteins stacking over possibilities is exactly my concern.

Answer (score 1):

This is not redundant but simply replacing C's  with a `:`. (And of course turning around type and identifier.)

Comment: I think it is not that simple.  As stated by @Kirsteins in the previous answer, : was introduced to enable external parameters, which leads to the possibilities of two different function invocation styles: the C/C++/Java style (without external parameters) and the OC style (with external parameters). I am afraid that there would be deadly fights between these styles in many teams using Swift when they create new libraries.

Comment: Kirsteins' answer is correct. But *in your example* the ` ` is simply replaced by an `:`, so there is nothing redundant.